# Why the first keystroke `win + space` for language input method switch is not switching in win10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, input-languages

### Situation

I have **2 language input methods**,

- one is the normal built-in US keyboard, for language English
- one is an 3rd party software input method, for language LANG_A

I allow "Let me use a different input method for each app window" in "Advanced keyboard settings"

I have hotkey `win + space` for switching the input method

#### .before

I press `win + space` once -> the input method is switched between English & LANG_A (everything works fine)

### Problem

#### .now

I press `win + space` once -> the input method is **NOT switched** between English & LANG_A,

instead, only the input method switcher panel is popped up (as usual), but not doing any switching

and I have to **not release** `win` key, and press `space` **one more time** so that it knows to switch.

##### notes::

- if you decide to **release** the `win` key, and hope to just press `win + space` one more time so it will work

  -- no, it will always only stays in the same input method

  -- as said >"only the input method switcher panel is popped up (as usual), but not doing any switching"
- this happens occasionally, not every time
- this happens mostly after you **switched from one window to another**
- this never happened before, but only after a recent windows update (within 3 weeks?)
- when I switch from one window to another, I can see the 3rd party input method panel blinks a lot

##### additional problems

<sub>the 3rd party input method panel becomes invisible when you switch to Google Chrome,

only shows up when you place the caret in an input area

(I dont think it behaves like this before)</sub>

### Question

**Why & How to fix this?**

(So that I dont need to press the keystroke twice.)

---

### Solution (workaround)

<sub>When I was using `Win7`, I was not able to use `win + space` for switching the keyboard.

But I did know ahk, and I found a [ahk post](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/24666-keyboard-layout-switcher/) that can do that.

When I use `Win10`, that was not needed.

But now, I need to use it as the workaround for that problem in Win10.</sub>

Use ahk (from that ahk post)::

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force 

#Space::LangSwitch(1)
#Space up::LangSwitch(2)

getKeyboardLanguID() {
  SetFormat, Integer, H
  WinGet, WinID,, A
  ThreadID:=DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "UInt", WinID, "UInt", 0)
  InputLocaleID:=DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", ThreadID, "UInt")
  return %InputLocaleID%
}

LangSwitch( iKeyDownUp=0 )
{
  static tickLast
  IfEqual,iKeyDownUp,1
  { tickLast=%A_TickCount%
    return
  }
  IfEqual,iKeyDownUp,2
    If( A_TickCount-tickLast>200 )
      return

  HKL:=DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "uint",GetThreadOfWindow(), "uint")

  HKLnum:=DllCall("GetKeyboardLayoutList","uint",0,"uint",0)
  VarSetCapacity( HKLlist, HKLnum*4, 0 )
  DllCall("GetKeyboardLayoutList","uint",HKLnum,"uint",&HKLlist)
  loop,%HKLnum%
  { if( NumGet( HKLlist, (A_Index-1)*4 ) = HKL )
    {   HKL:=NumGet( HKLlist, mod(A_Index,HKLnum)*4 )
      break
    }
  }
  ControlGetFocus,ctl,A
  SendMessage,0x50,0,HKL,%ctl%,A ;WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST

/*  
  ;show traytip
  LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE=0x1001
  LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY=0x1002
  VarSetCapacity( sKbd, 260, 0 )
  VarSetCapacity( sCountry, 260, 0 )
  DllCall("GetLocaleInfo","uint",HKL>>16,"uint",LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, "str",sKbd, "uint",260)
  DllCall("GetLocaleInfo","uint",HKL & 0xFFFF,"uint",LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY, "str",sCountry, "uint",260)
  traytip,%sKbd%,%sCountry%
  SetTimer,REMOVE_TOOLTIP,500 ;0.5 second
  return
REMOVE_TOOLTIP:
  SetTimer,REMOVE_TOOLTIP,off
  traytip
  return 
*/
}

;returns first thread for the <processID>
;sets optional <List> to pipe | separated thread list for the <processID>
GetProcessThreadOrList( processID, byRef list="" )
{
  ;THREADENTRY32 {
  THREADENTRY32_dwSize=0 ; DWORD
  THREADENTRY32_cntUsage = 4    ;DWORD
  THREADENTRY32_th32ThreadID = 8    ;DWORD
  THREADENTRY32_th32OwnerProcessID = 12 ;DWORD
  THREADENTRY32_tpBasePri = 16  ;LONG
  THREADENTRY32_tpDeltaPri = 20 ;LONG
  THREADENTRY32_dwFlags = 24    ;DWORD
  THREADENTRY32_SIZEOF = 28

  TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD=4

  hProcessSnap := DllCall("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot","uint",TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, "uint",0)
  ifEqual,hProcessSnap,-1, return

  VarSetCapacity( thE, THREADENTRY32_SIZEOF, 0 )
  NumPut( THREADENTRY32_SIZEOF, thE )

  ret=-1

  if( DllCall("Thread32First","uint",hProcessSnap, "uint",&thE ))
    loop
    {
      if( NumGet( thE ) >= THREADENTRY32_th32OwnerProcessID + 4)
        if( NumGet( thE, THREADENTRY32_th32OwnerProcessID ) = processID )
        {   th := NumGet( thE, THREADENTRY32_th32ThreadID )
          IfEqual,ret,-1
            ret:=th
          list .=  th "|"
        }
      NumPut( THREADENTRY32_SIZEOF, thE )
      if( DllCall("Thread32Next","uint",hProcessSnap, "uint",&thE )=0)
        break
    }

  DllCall("CloseHandle","uint",hProcessSnap)
  StringTrimRight,list,list,1
  return ret
}

; Returns thread owning specified window handle
; default = Active window
GetThreadOfWindow( hWnd=0 )
{
  IfEqual,hWnd,0
    hWnd:=WinExist("A")
  DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "uint",hWnd, "uintp",id)
  GetProcessThreadOrList(  id, threads )
  IfEqual,threads,
    return 0
  CB:=RegisterCallback("GetThreadOfWindowCallBack","Fast")
  lRet=0
  lParam:=hWnd
  loop,parse,threads,|
  { NumPut( hWnd, lParam )
    DllCall("EnumThreadWindows", "uint",A_LoopField, "uint",CB, "uint",&lParam)
    if( NumGet( lParam )=true )
    {   lRet:=A_LoopField
      break
    }
  }
  DllCall("GlobalFree", "uint", CB)
  return lRet
}

GetThreadOfWindowCallBack( hWnd, lParam )
{
  IfNotEqual,hWnd,% NumGet( 0+lParam )
    return true
  NumPut( true, 0+lParam )
  return 0
}
```

Comment: _Where_ did you _set `win + space` for switching the input method_? This key combination is default for [Switch input language and keyboard layout](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10).

Comment: @JosefZ (Somehow I thought I did it manually, but it seems not possible; but anyways, that is not the main point of the problem)